# How to strip last element of dash delimited string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string delimited with dashes like:

```
x#-ls-foobar-takemeoff-
```

How can I remove `takemeoff-` using javascript where `takemeoff-` can be any amount of characters ending in a dash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var str = "x#-ls-foobar-takemeoff-";
var newStr = str.replace(/[^-]+-$/,"");
```

Basic regular expression says

```
[^-]+  <-- Match any characters that is not a dash
-      <-- Match a dash character
$      <-- Match the end of a string
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string `str`, you can do the following:

```
str = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf("-", str.length - 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `substr()` and `lastIndexOf()`:

```
var myStr = "x#-ls-foobar-takemeoff-";

myStr = myStr.substr(0, myStr.length-1); // remove the trailing -

var lastDash = myStr.lastIndexOf('-'); // find the last -
myStr = myStr.substr(0, lastDash);

alert(myStr);
```

Outputs:

> x#-ls-foobar

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zDWyK/).